# Cannot change HDMI brightness on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: display, hdmi, brightness

I cannot change by any mean the brightness of a monitor connected through hdmi to an AMD rx 550 videocard on ubuntu 22.04. I used to be able before changing a now dead geforce, I did a fresh install after the new videocard. Its the only active monitor.
I tried this command "xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.1" with no luck.
more info:
xrandr -q | grep " connected"

XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a posible answer, just install  `gddccontrol` by running

```
sudo apt install ddccontrol
sudo apt install gddccontrol
```

and you'll be able to control the brightness of your monitor. Hope it's useful for someone.